# using two sqldependency in one application

Tags: sqldependency

my win application have two SqlDependency against two tables on the same database, but only one of them work correctly(the last one).
I guessed using  SqlDependency.Start(connection, queue Name) and creating two separate queue solve this problem but it made this error :

"When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.  "

Answer (score 0):

I find my mistake ,I worte :

SqlDependency.Stop(MYConnectionString);
SqlDependency.Start(MYConnectionString)

before each 'MYSqlDependency.AddCommandDependency(MYCommand)'

then each sqldependency has closed when the next one was creating.